# angular : ng-bind from view to position outside view

Tags: javascript, grails, data-binding, angularjs

if this is solvable with $rootScope, how can i achieve this?
my code is below, inside the view it works fine,
as soon as i place the element outside of the view it breaks.

controller

```
$http.get('testData.json').success(function(data) {
     angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
            if (item.id == $routeParams.detailId) 
              $scope.article = item;
              $scope.category = $scope.article.category;
          });
      });
```

populated input from controller

```
<input type="text" ng-model="category">
```

ng-bind element outside controller

```
<h1 ng-bind-template="Hello, {{category}}"></h1>
```

i tried to load the data in rootScope, whats not worked,
furthermore $rootScope window

```
    .run(function($rootScope, $window) {
    $rootScope.window = $window;
});
```

Comment: Why not use two controllers and a shared service? Data should come from a service anyway.

Comment: its working now, have you a snippet for service data loading? then i can close/resolve this issue as well.

Comment: http://ericterpstra.com/2012/09/angular-cats-part-1-the-data-service/